# Java: bad operand type

Tags: java

I'm a beginner so sorry if the question is stupid.

I have wrote following code:

```
public class Traindata {
String City;

public Traindata(String t_city) { 


    if(t_city == "Judenburg" || "Knittelfeld" || "Zeltweg" || "Leoben" || "Bruck/Mur" || "Kapfenberg") {
        City = t_city;
    } else {
        System.out.println("City not allowed: " + t_city + "\n");
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if t_city is the same as one of the allowed Cities (Judenburg, Knittelfeld, Zeltweg, Leoben).

But when I try to compile the code, I get this error-message:
"error: bad operand type for binary operator '|'"

So can anybodye help me with this? I think I used the  "||" wrong, but I just can't get it to work.

E: Thanks everyone, I didn't even know equals() existed.

Comment: As a design suggestion, if you're going to use those names anywhere you may want to put them in a `Set<String>` beforehand and check if `t_city` is any one of those cities by using the `Set.contains(t_city)` function.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: No need to apologize for being a beginner.

Comment: Interesting error for the above scenario. The error should be "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String". Which version of Java do you use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems in your code: you need to use `equals` to compare Java strings, and you need to repeatedly use the comparison to construct an `||` expression:

```
if(t_city.equals("Judenburg") || t_city.equals("Knittelfeld") ... )
```

Better yet, construct a `HashSet<String>` of the cities that you wish to match, and use `contains` method to check the condition:

```
Set<String> cities = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "Judenburg", "Knittelfeld", "Zeltweg", "Leoben", "Bruck/Mur", "Kapfenberg"
));
...
if (cities.contains(t_city)) {
    ...
}
```

Here is a [demo of this later approach on ideone](http://ideone.com/clT4Si).

Comment: `Set<String> cities = ImmutableSet.of("Judenburg", "Knittelfeld", "Zeltweg", "Leoben", "Bruck/Mur", "Kapfenberg")` (guava style)

Comment: +1, but even without the Guava classes, you don't need `new String[] {...`. Just `Arrays.asList("Judenburg", "Knittelfeld", ...));

Comment: Using a set makes the most sense here, +1

Answer (score 9):

```
 if(t_city == "Judenburg" || "Knittelfeld" || "Zeltweg" || "Leoben" ||...
```

two issues:

1) Use `equals()` for `String` comparison

```
"Judenburg".equals(t_city)
```

2)   Your code should be something like below:

`if("Judenburg".equals(t_city) || "Knittelfeld".equals(t_city) ......`

Comment: and "constant".equals() avoid a potential NPE

Comment: @RC. I tend to avoid yoda conditions with strings. If my string is null, I want to know about it!

Answer (score 3):

The `||` (or) operator connects two boolean expressions and returns a boolean. When you write:

```
t_city == "Judenburg" || "Knittelfeld"
```

The left side of the `||` is the expression `t_city == "Judenburg"` which correctly evaluates to a boolean, but the right hand side is `"Knittelfeld"` which is not a boolean, but a string!

You should write this:

```
(t_city == "Judenburg") || (t_city == "Knittelfeld") || (t_city == "Zeltweg") || (t_city == "Leoben") || (t_city == "Bruck/Mur") || (t_city == "Kapfenberg")
```

In that way, every expression between parentheses is a boolean expression.

Edit: You should also change how you compare strings. `t_city == "Judenburg"` compares pointers, which is not what you want. Use: `t_city.equals("Judenburg")` instead.